# NoSQL equivalent to SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: database, nosql

have been trying out MongoDB. In total, it is a cool thing. But typing in a cmd is just not my thing. Have tried out a web based interface called adminMongo. Nothing wrong with it, but it doesn't look pretty. Wondering what is the nearest NoSQL (doesn't have to be MongoDB) equivalent to SQL Server Management Studio? 
All web based or are there softwares?

Answer (score 0):

Try NoSQL Viewer (http://www.spviewer.com/nosqlviewer.html). Its free and supports multiple NoSQL databases including MangoDB and Couchbase